# How to #include "include/libxsmm.h" when I try to add a new op in tensorflow?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am trying to add a new conv op in tensorflow, and I need to use *libxsmm* to speed up my conv cal. And I tried to follow the tensorflow source code but I find it difficult to `include "include/libxsmm.h"` like https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/xsmm_conv2d_test.cc

Anyone can help me = =

Also, I want to know whether a `float matrix` in `libxsmm` can access a block of a matrix easily? such as `a[n,h,:,:]`?

I know how to access a single value by:

```
LIBXSMM_VLA_ACCESS(4,  input, k, c, r, s, C, R, S);
```

A lot of thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To include libxsmm.h, you may want to rely on TENSORFLOW_USE_LIBXSMM (if you work on a translation unit, which is not specifically dedicated to *libxsmm*). For example, **xsmm**_conv2d_test.cc includes libxsmm.h right away as it only targets *libxsmm* (afore mentioned test is upfront / somewhere else). However, for instance [sparse_matmul_op.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/sparse_matmul_op.cc#L41) checks if TENSORFLOW_USE_LIBXSMM is defined (this translation unit implements sparse operators even when *libxsmm* is not present).

If you want to operate on a submatrix using *libxsmm*, this requires that the function in *libxsmm* takes a stride (leading dimension). It would be helpful to know what kind of function you want to use from *libxsmm* (matrix operation or convolution).

Comment: A lot of thanks, I actually need to implement submatrix multiplication using libxsmm, I don't know if it is possible..

Comment: See https://github.com/hfp/eigen/blob/master/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorContraction.h (this is only a fork of Eigen, which also contains experimental code). See also https://github.com/hfp/libxsmm/tree/master/samples/eigen (please note, this matrix multiplication appears to perform only reasonable).

Comment: I hope to come up with something inside of LIBXSMM, which is well tuned ([XGEMM](https://github.com/hfp/libxsmm/tree/master/samples/xgemm) is only an incomplete starting point, and [BGEMM](https://github.com/hfp/libxsmm/tree/master/samples/bgemm) requires copy-in and copy-out. Both XGEMM and BGEMM are experimental each with own [limitations](https://github.com/hfp/libxsmm/issues/186#issuecomment-316390653).